# directive compiled after bootstrap is not working after minification

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, lazy-loading

If I declare a directive like so (inspired by http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/):

```
myApp.compileProvider
    .directive('myDirective', 
        ['$http', '$timeout', 
        function($http, $timeout){
            return {
                (...)
            }
        }]);
```

It works as expected before minification.

But after it returns an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: iProvider <- i
```

Suggesting that a dependency is not declared.

Is there a different syntax for minification safe lazy loaded directive dependencies ?

Comment: the [inline notification for dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) should work... any chance it's not this directive that's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forget to do the correct injection somewhere in your code, meaning doing this :

```
function($http, $service,...)
```

Instead of this

```
['$http', '$service', [...], function($http, $service,...){}]
```

If you want more information about where you have a problem you should enable strict-di by adding ng-strict-di along with your ng-app tag. Check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: The method you suggest is not minification safe

Comment: yes it is i'm suggesting the 2nd block, it's minification safe. What i'm saying is that it's probably not from his directive but somewhere else in his code.